# Difference between read and write access (data, IoT)

Tags: data, legal, portability, access, iot

i am a lawyer and currently writing an essay about data access in ioT environments. I often stumble over the distinction between read access and write access. Could someone provide me with an example, preferably in an ioT, mobile app oder plattform context.

(a little context for those who are interested: My argument is that many complementary IoT services require not just read but write access.)

Thank you very much!!

Comment: see [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7538/31260)

Comment: If you don't understand the distinction between read and write access, then you don't appear to be in a position to write an essay on the subject.

Comment: Do you mean reading and writing to the device from a server, to the server from the device, to the server from a user config page on the internet?

Comment: This reminds me of the time I asked an admin to submit a request for write access and he wrote 'right access'.  I explained "I mean write with a 'W'"  Later I saw that the request was submitted for "wright" access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading data means looking at it. Writing data means changing it. This is fairly basic computing jargon.

For example, when you look at your bank statement online, that is a read; when you send money to someone, that is a write.

I hope you can see why writing might be considered more dangerous than reading.

The word "access" can mean the reading and writing itself, or it can mean whether they're *allowed* to read and write the data - it's often clear from the context. I could say that "I gave you read-only access to my bank account", which means I told the bank's computer system to allow you to look at my bank account, but not change it. Read-only access can help to mitigate security threats - if someone finds out your password, they can see what's in my account but they can't steal the money.

If a device needs write access to do its job, obviously you can't give it read-only access as a security mitigation, because then it wouldn't be able to do its job.

Comment: Thank you very much for your enlightening answer on this topic! Best regards from switzerland!